# Filter Document Library items using query string

Tags: 2010, search, document-library, query-string

I have document library (Images Type) and when using the following quick filter paramters nothing happens

```
?FilterName=LinkTitle&FilterMultiValue=*%d8%b3%d8%b9%d8%a7%d8%af%d8%a9*;
```

I tried this

```
?FilterField1=LinkTitle&FiterValue1=*%d8%b3%d8%b9%d8%a7%d8%af%d8%a9*;
```

but this only works when the `FiterValue1` equals exactly one or more item's LinkTitle field

any suggestions how to implement `contains` using filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the library's `displayform` and add a `query string` parameter, and then `Filter` content using that passed parameter through the `query string`.
needed some javascript and an `input` element to redirect to the same form but with the parameter included in the URL

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering using `contains` isn't implemented in the OOTB SharePoint ListViews, so you have to create your own web part or probably better use search.